# Function Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I am new to Haskell. I want to have a function in which I get an Int value from the user using

```
putStr "Please Enter Your Number : "
submit_ans<- getLine
```

then after a series of calculations returns another Int which will be used by another function that has called it. What is the type of the described function? should I use return function at the end?

### thanks in advance!

Update #1

ok I updated the function as below:

```
myFunction ::  Int -> IO Int 
myFunction action = do

      putStr "\tPlease Enter Your Number : "            
      submit_ans <- getLine 

      if action == 1
        then do 
       myFunctionII read submit_ans  
        else do
       putStrLn("\n")
```

it gives me this error:

```
*** Term           : myFunction 
*** Type           : Int -> IO Int
*** Does not match : IO a
```

Comment: This "other function" you mention, what's its type? From your comments further down, it sounds like it's a pure function (i.e. non-IO). You can't perform an IO action from a pure function.

Comment: @gspr So that's the problem! I didn't know that I can't have IO actions in pure funtion! Then again, what's the point of `IO Int` if one cannot use the returned value?

Comment: Sure you can use it. But only from within the `IO` monad. Part of the "point" is indeed to dinstinguish between pure (non-IO) and impure (IO) code! A pure function always returns the same when given the same input. An impure one could burn down your house and eat your cat every third full moon on days beginning with s. It's nice to be able to treat the two kinds of functions differently.

Comment: So what I'm saying is: Write an IO-function that uses `getLine` to get the number, and then *from that function* call the pure functions that you want do stuff with the number you got (which you can get, since you're in the IO monad now). In other words: Have the IO code call the pure code, not the other way around.

Comment: I think I get the idea. I will try to implement it now. thanks!

Comment: @gspr  I updated the post. would you please check it?

Comment: use parentheses: `myFunctionII (read submit_ans)`. Also, `do something` is the same as `something`. Also, please copy your code more accurately, and provide fuller error message. :)

Comment: done but still the same error.

Comment: your code `if action == "1"` says to Haskell that `action` is of type `String`, but you declare it (in your function's signature) as `Int`.

Comment: oh the code is so long I thought it would give you a headache reading a long code written by a newbie.

Comment: but what is `myFunctionII`? ... and I meant fuller error message, not code. But you can also `hpaste.org` the code in full and give us a link.

Comment: `myFunctionII` is `myFunctionII::  Int -> IO ()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23369/discussion-between-will-ness-and-elham)

Answer (score 2):

Just write your function, say `g`, as a pure calculation, of type `Int -> Int`. Then you use it in IO monad as

```
...
putStr "Please Enter Your Number : "
submit_ans <- getLine
let i = g (read submit_ans)
...
print i
```

edit: Any Haskell value is pure. Functions are pure. `IO x` is a pure Haskell value. But it *describes* an impure computation, which *will be* run by the system (say, when your compiled application is run). As part of *its* execution, it will execute your pure function.

Answer (score 2):

`putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()` and it seems `myFunctionII` has type `Int -> IO ()`, so the type of `myFunction` should be `Int -> IO ()` since both branches of your `if` return an `IO ()`:

```
myFunction :: Int -> IO ()
myFunction action = do
  putStr "\tPlease Enter Your Number : "
  submit_ans <- getLine

  if action == 1
     then myFunctionII (read submit_ans)
     else putStrLn "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are performing an IO operation and you are returning an `Int` so my best guess would be `IO Int` but I can't tell for sure because you question is too vague to answer clearly.

Comment: actually I did try `myFunction :: IO Int` but like I mentioned, another function calls this function and uses the returned `Int` value  as an argument. it gave me error telling me IO Int is not Int.

Comment: Read about IO monad. You can't call an IO function inside a pure function (non IO types) cause that will break referential transparency. If you callee is also an IO function then you can do how you did for getLine.

Comment: I get your point but using `IO Int` and trying to call the pure function from within the function with IO actions did not work either. (I updated the post)